# How to fix UTF-8 issues with command execution

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, utf-8, windows-console

When I execute a command using backticks and print that output with `puts` it displays question marks instead of the right characters.
This is my code (just a test to make it easier for you to read):

```
# encoding: utf-8

# Trying without encoding after
puts `echo Just ä täst`

# Trying with encoding after
puts `echo Just ä täst`.encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"0")
```

The output is as follows:

```
Just � t�st
Just 0 t0st
```

Also if I try to split this with

```
puts `echo Just ä täst`.split(" ")
```

I get following error:

```
./utf_test.rb:9:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from ./utf_test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

BUT when I just print to the screen it works i.e. `puts 'just ä täst'` results in `just ä täst` being printed.

Comment: You could try with different [code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page), like `437`, `850`, `1252`, `65001`, using the [`chcp` command](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl I can see umlauts perfectly fine in the cmd. Also I am in germany and the page you linked states that the codepage with umlauts should be selected. It's only not working when I get umlauts returned from using command execution within ruby (see last sentence of my question). Otherwise I can perfectly fine use them within ruby and within the cmd.

Comment: Try `\`echo Just ä täst\`.force_encoding("UTF-8")`.

Comment: UTF-8 is codepage 65001, but the console's support for UTF-8 is broken for both output and input prior to Windows 8, and still broken for reading non-ASCII input in the latest Windows 10. That's why Python switched to using the console's wide-character Unicode API (i.e. `ReadConsoleW`, `WriteConsoleW`) instead of the legacy codepage API (i.e. `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, `ReadConsoleA`, `WriteConsoleA`). Maybe Ruby has a package that implements something similar.